# PPA without release file

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa

I am trying to install a tool called Stacer, to clean junk files from my PC (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

The app is installed but everytime is use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error

> Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu focal InRelease
>   Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu focal Release
>     404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
>   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

What should I do?

**EDIT 1**
The question is not answered at [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file).

They suggest to remove the PPA. But the error message says it is disabled by default. So there might be a way to enable it.

Comment: @Pilot6 The question isnt answered there either. All the answers there tell to remove that PPA. So I am asking a way to install updates from that PPA. The error message says it is blocked by default. So is there a way to enable it.

Comment: This PPA doesn't support  Ubuntu 20.04. Isn't it clear?

Comment: @Pilot6 where does it say the PPA isnt supported for 20.04? Atleast I dont think it is clear. Where is it written?

Comment: Did you read the link I gave? "The PPA you've added does not support your version of Ubuntu". It is written in ` focal Release 404 Not Found`. And also you can see it at https://launchpad.net/~oguzhaninan/+archive/ubuntu/stacer  The last one was 19.04.

Comment: PPA stands for **personal package archive**. The person who maintains the archive, has to build a package specifically for 20.04. you can't do anything. It is completely up to that person. If and when they can or want they may or may not build the package for 20.04. If that person is dead, there may never be another new package in that PPA.

Comment: @Pilot6 Oh sorry my bad.I thought in that answer they were talking specifically about ppa:mc3man/trusty-media.

Comment: @user68186 yes. But again i ddint focus much on that, cause i thought that specific ppa was outdated

Comment: That's not a good idea. I maintain some PPAs. And I don't upgrade each and every one. I don't want to be contacted and asked to do something I don't want ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I hear you. PPA maintainer are people too. Bugging them for something they don't want to do is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent version of Ubuntu supported by the PPA is disco, not focal.
A solution is to go in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and open the file called something similar to stacer.list

Inside the file, replace the string:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu focal main
```

with

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu disco main
```

(in other words, replace focal with disco)

Comment: Well, but it is not guaranteed that it will install.

Comment: In general, adding PPA of different release can sometimes create sependency issues.

Comment: Mixing repositories from different releases is not advised. You risk getting all kinds of dependency problems.

Comment: But anyhow the software did get installed.

Comment: @AbhayPatil If you already followed this answer, you may want to change the string back from `disco` to `focal`. That way if the PPA gets updated you will get proper the version for 20.04. If not the repository will less likely to cause problems later.

Comment: @user68186 I installed it prior all this knowledge as mentioned in the question. Currently I have unchecked this PPA from Software & Updates.